# How can I get back id and time from insert?

Tags: java, sql, derby

I have table like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE example
(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  number DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT DATE
);
```

I am able to get back id with code

```
Connection connection = null;
try {
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/database","root","root");
  connection.setAutoCommit(false);
  PreparedStatement query = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO example (number) VALUES (?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
  query.setInt(1, 12);
  query.executeUpdate();

  ResultSet rs = query.getGeneratedKeys();

  while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
    //System.out.println(rs.getDate(2));
  }

  connection.commit();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  if(connection != null){
    try {
      connection.rollback();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
      Logger.getLogger("meh").log(Level.SEVERE, null, e1);
    }
  }
  Logger.getLogger("meh").log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
}finally {
  try {
    if(connection != null)
      connection.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    Logger.getLogger("meh").log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
  }
}
```

But when I tried to uncomment second println, error showed up: "The column position '2' is out of range.  The number of columns for this ResultSet is '1'.". So is here any way how to get back that time?

Comment: yes it should be number thanks.

Comment: You could search for the registered element and get the `date` field.

Comment: getGeneratedKeys will return only the id. date has a default value but is not a generated key. To get both, you need to do a regular query on the table, using the generated key you've got

Comment: Uh @Leo thank you, I was hoping there is way how to do it without that.

Comment: If this is something you're going to do regularly (insert a row, then retrieve it to examine its values), package that in a subroutine so it's easy for you to call.